# Confused about oracle db and sid's

Tags: oracle

On sql server usually I create multiple db(mysql,postgresql)

On oracle I know(probably wrong) that for one db you need one instance

but this use a lot of memory(over 20G used for 2 sids on test server)

The question is..is possible to use one SID and multiple DB's on oracle?

Comment: before version 12c, no - one db would be one instance of oracle running In 12c and higher, you can use the multitenant option to run multiple (pluggable) databases in a single instance of a database. in 12c world, the SID is the identifier of the container database responsible for all of the pluggable databases running inside of it - they share resources where appropriate

Comment: thanks,if add this as answer I can close the question and vote + for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: use pluggable DB.